# Метод onCreate() у сервиса вызывается несколько раз

Tags: android, service

После запуска сервиса в onCreate моего MainActivity я уничтожаю приложение через последние приложения. По идее должна уничтожиться только Activity, но вместе с ней, почему-то, умирает и сервис. Сам сервис нужен для мониторига сервера на новые задачи. Как сделать так, чтобы сервис не перезапускался и не зависил от жизни приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Долго искал информацию об этом. Как оказалось сервис выключается вместе с приложением и исправить это никак не получится. Единственный способ это вызвать метод startForeground(int, Notification) в сервисе, после чего нотификация сервиса будет висеть в статусбаре.

Comment: Вот как раз такое поведение мне и необходимо, и вроде даже работает) Спасибо. Что касается висящего уведомления, можно первым параметром передать 0 и иконка не будет отображаться.

Comment: Исправить всё можно, просто объявить в манифесте, что сервис будет выполняться в другом процессе.

Answer (score 2):

Сие действие можно реализовать многими способами. Можно сделать точно такой же сервис, как вы и делали, только выделить под него новый процесс в манифесте, всю потом внутри него создать отдельный поток при запуске, т.к. если этого не сделать, то при выполнении длительных операций можно получить ANR ошибку и сервис грохнется, далее нужно в **onStartCommand()** в **return** отправлять флаг **Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT**, подробнее [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/159-urok-94-service-podrobno-pro-onstartcommand.html)

Comment: Именно так и поступил, просто забыл упомянуть о новом процессе в манифесте

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся недавно с этой проблемой, как пишут [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677827/2323537), нужно переопределить метод `onTaskRemoved` в сервисе, таким образом:

```
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.e("FLAGX : ", ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK + "");
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

это в теории должно было перезапускать сервис, но на практике на некоторых устройствах это не работало, пока в манифесте не добавил `android:stopWithTask="false"` в тэг сервиса. Но это все только перезапустит сервис, а система продолжит его убивать. Если у кого-то есть более правильное решение, рад буду услышать.

Answer (score 1):

> Сам сервис нужен для мониторига сервера на новые задачи.

Возможно Вам лучше реализовать это с помощью PUSH-уведомлений.